# Ingresar caracteres de forma continua en la terminal sin necesidad de pulsar Enter

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdin

Me gustaría crear un programa que fuese leyendo caracteres introducidos por el usuario pero de forma continua, sin tener que pulsar <kbd>Enter</kbd> cada vez que meto uno y que pare de leer, por ejemplo, al introducir un '.'

Algo así como:

```
palabra = []

while True:
    letra = input()
    if letra == '.':
        break
    else:
        palabra.append(letra)
```

Comment: Bienvenido para entender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio te invito a dar un [tour]

Answer (score 1):

Ni `input` ni `sys.stdout.read` te van a valer para leer carácter a carácter sin el debido EOL. Para esto vas a tener que trabajar a más bajo nivel con la terminal de turno. En Windows puedes usar el módulo [`msvcrt`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/msvcrt.html#console-i-o) y las funciones `getch`, `getche`, `getwch` y `getwche`:

```
import msvcrt


palabra = []

while True:
    letra = msvcrt.getwche()
    if letra == '.':
        break
    else:
        palabra.append(letra)

print("\n" + "".join(palabra))
```

En POSIX puedes usar [`termios`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/termios.html?highlight=termios#module-termios):

```
import os
import sys
import termios


file_descriptor = sys.stdin.fileno()
old = termios.tcgetattr(file_descriptor)
new = old[:]

palabra = []

try:
    new[3] &= ~(termios.ICANON | termios.ECHOCTL)
    termios.tcsetattr(file_descriptor, termios.TCSADRAIN, new)

    while True:
        letra = sys.stdin.read(1)
        if letra == '.':
            break
        else:
            palabra.append(letra)
finally:
    termios.tcsetattr(file_descriptor, termios.TCSADRAIN, old)


print("\n" + "".join(palabra))
```

En ambos casos el carácter es impreso cuando se ingresa, aunque podemos hacer que no sea así si lo deseamos:

- En Windows cambiar `msvcrt.getwche` por `msvcrt.getwch`.
- En POSIX cambiar la línea:

  ```
    new[3] &= ~(termios.ICANON | termios.ECHOCTL)
  ```

  por:

  ```
    new[3] &= ~(termios.ICANON | termios.ECHO)
  ```

> **Nota:** El script a de ejecutarse en la terminal del sistema directamente. Normalmente no va a funcionar en la terminal o intérprete interactivo del IDE de turno.