# ¿Como hago un "Presione enter para continuar" en Python 3? (Linux)

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Buenas.**
Me preguntaba como poner el típico mensaje de "Presiona Enter para continuar" o "Presiona una tecla para continuar"

Pero sin utilizar un input:
`input("Presiona Enter para continuar")`
Porque queda mal que el usuario pueda escribir texto después. Además si lo intento con input, el usuario tiene que escribir algo antes de pulsar el enter.
Sé que hay una pregunta similar pero era para windows.

**Muchas gracias c:**

Comment: Encontré una respuesta bastante elegante en SO en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16933120/11649862 para Windows o para Linux! Aunque te permite ingresar otras teclas... Pero quizás te sirve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aunque parece algo trivial, no lo es principalmente porque es plataforma - dependiente. Tienes varias posibilidades, en Linux (realmente en cualquier sistema dentro del estándar POSIX) una de ellas es hacer uso del módulo [termios](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/termios.html) de la stdlib. Hay varias preguntas relacionadas con el problema de obtener una tecla pulsada sin necesidad de pulsar <kbd>Enter</kbd>, como:

- [Ingresar caracteres de forma continua en la terminal sin necesidad de pulsar Enter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/156006/15089)
- [Obtener tecla presionada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/102987/15089).

Algo así debería valer para la mayoría de casos, sin necesidad de usar módulos externos en sistemas POSIX:

```
import sys
import termios

def wait_for(mess, *keys):
    file_descriptor = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old = termios.tcgetattr(file_descriptor)
    new = old[:]

    try:
        new[3] &= ~(termios.ICANON | termios.ECHO)
        termios.tcsetattr(file_descriptor, termios.TCSADRAIN, new)
        print(mess, end="")
        while True:
            letra = sys.stdin.read(1)
            if not keys or letra in keys:
                print()
                break
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(file_descriptor, termios.TCSADRAIN, old)
```

> ```
> wait_for("Presione Enter para continuar", '\n')    
> wait_for("Presione una tecla para continuar")
> wait_for("Presione Esc para continuar", '\x1b')
> wait_for("Presione 'Q' para continuar", 'q', 'Q')
> wait_for("Presione 'Q' o 'E' para continuar", 'q', 'Q', 'e', 'E')
> ```

- `~termios.ICANON` deshabilita el modo canónico o de edición de línea, de forma que la entrada es puesta a disposición del programa inmediatamente en vez de permitir editar la linea y pulsar <kbd>Enter</kbd> para ingresar.
- `~termios.ECHO` impide que el input sea inmediatamente mostrado en la terminal, de esta forma no se imprime nada cuando se pulsa una tecla.

Obviamente la función se puede mejorar, por ejemplo en la forma de especificar la tecla o teclas, pero ya nos permite esperar que cualquier tecla sea pulsada o a que una en concreto lo sea (o una dentro de una lista de teclas), sin necesidad de pulsar <kbd>Enter</kbd> y sin mostrar cualquier tecla que el usuario presione como ocurre con `input()`.

---

> **Nota**: No hay garantía de que funcione en la terminal integrada de un IDE.  Funciona en VScode por ejemplo, pero no en la terminal emulada de IDLE. Por lo tanto se recomienda ejecutar el código en la terminal del sistema.